# Hide base path before # in url in Angular

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, angular

I'm building a wordpress theme with angular as described [here](http://doppiaeast.com/series/angular-2-wordpress-theme/).

This is my index.html that is loaded by wordpress' index.php:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TITLE</title>

  <base href="/wp-content/themes/TITLE/dist/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The url result is:
http://HOST/wp-content/themes/TITLE/dist/#/ , but should be http://HOST/#/

I need to set the  tag in my index.html to enable angular to find its resources. Is there a way to hide the /wp-content/themes/TITLE/dist part before the /#/ from angulars HashLocationStrategy?

I would prefer to hide it from the angular settings, but if a wordpress configuration in the admin view is necessary this would be fine, too.

Comment: Everything before the `/#/` is used by the server to locate the resource. If you want to get rid of that you'll need to configure the server to do so. Nothing to do with angular. If you want to get rid of the `#` itself, you'll need to configure angular, and if you want to be able to link to the bits angular understands you need to configure both.

Comment: But the server already knows where to find my index.html. Is it possible to set the <base> tag from the location of the index.html? For example <base href="./dist/"> And show only /dist/ in the url?

Comment: The base tag is only used by the browser. The part after the host name and before the `#` is used by the web server to locate a file to serve. The part after `#` is traditionally used to link to a specific place on the page, as such it is only used by the browser. You can remove parts of the URL using techniques like URL-Rewriting, but that's outside my realm of knowledge for PHP which is why I didn't give a direct answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will have a look at URL rewriting then.